# Copy Polygon from one feature class to another, but auto create relationship records

Tags: arcgis-online, geoprocessing-service, arcgis-portal

FYI, I have a very limited GIS background, but I can author code.

I have a Stands (polygon) layer and I want a user to be able to copy stand(s) from this layer and paste it to another polygon layer (say a HarvestActivity).

When the paste occurs I want to record the following in a related table of the HarvestActivity feature class that the polys were pasted into.

**StandId** - Id of stand from source "stand" layer

**AreaOfStand** - this is the area of the polygon of the HarvestActivity layer that covers a stand from the stands layer.

**AreaPercent** - the percentage ratio to the original stand

Another important note is that if someone edits the polygons in the activity layer, i.e. cuts or extend it. then the related table needs to be updated (changing the ratios, adding records, deleting records) automatically.

E.g. If I extend a polygon in the HarvestActivity Layer and that polygon overlaps with 3 stands in the stands layer then we would need to have 3 records created.

What is the best way to handle this in the GIS world? We will be using Portal and ArcGis Online, thus support of offline sync needs to be also considered.

Answer (score 1):

I can give you the workflow on how I would do this in ArcGIS Online

1. With an Organizational account publish a feature layer with the parent layer and the related table.
2. Create a  hosted feature layer view join from the published feature layer. Read about that here https://doc.arcgis.com/en/arcgis-online/analyze/join-features.htm
3. Edit the fields you need to in the view layer that has the joins and the edits will go back to the parent feature layer.

Comment: How do I handle this...Say a user has selected 4 polygons from the stands layer and paste them to the harvestactivity layer. The user then merges the 4 polygons into 1 polygon in the harvestactivity layer. I still need to show 4 records in the HarvestActivityStands table to capture spatially how the 1 polygon now relates to the stands layer.

Comment: hmm my workflow wont cover that case. Also merging the 4 polygons into one polygon would probbaly orphan some records without setting up a new primary and foreign key field to keep the relatonship to those other records.